# How can I send VBoxHeadless to the background so I can close the Terminal?

Tags: virtualbox, headless

I would like to start virtual machines in headless mode. The advantage: I can logoff from the desktop, and the machine will continue to run. However, starting the virtual machine blocks the Terminal from closing. Is there a clever solution to have everything like a service in the background? If I do 'sudo service ntp start' it will start, and then I can close the Terminal. I could do the following, but I'm not happy with it:

- `nohup VBoxHeadless -s "MyGuest" &`
- log in from a login shell (tty1-6) which is equipped with [Byobu](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/byobu/), start the VM, and instead of logging out I could detach with F6.

Better way of doing it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just found a solution [here](http://www.trimentation.com/wp/?p=71): Starting the the virtual machine with `VBoxManage` instead of `VBoxHeadless` solves my problem:

```
VBoxManage startvm <uuid|vmname> --type headless
```

For example, if your VM's name was **Ubuntu** and it had a UUID of **865b2700-471a-11e4-916c-0800200c9a66**, you can run:

```
VBoxManage startvm Ubuntu --type headless
```

or

```
VBoxManage startvm 865b2700-471a-11e4-916c-0800200c9a66 --type headless
```

Note: If the name of your VM contains spaces, wrap the name in quotes (e.g. `"My Ubuntu"`).

The machine goes nicely into the background. Now I can control the virtual machine with `VBoxManage controlvm` poweroff/pause/reset ([section 3.3](http://www.howtoforge.com/vboxheadless-running-virtual-machines-with-virtualbox-4.1-on-a-headless-ubuntu-12.04-server)).

Comment: Nice trick. You can always use VBoxManage controlvm even if you started a machine VBoXHeadless.

Comment: Great find! Here's the command for those who don't know `VBoxManage startvm Crunchbang --type headless`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem but NOHUP was not working. The problem was caused by X forward on my SSH connection:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=76342

Disabled X forward and then  &  and nohup where working fine